# How do I upload file in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a server backend that accept a multipart request with a JSON part and a file part. It is a RESTful web service. However I don't manage to get the fileuploading part to work. How can I do this?

Comment: You can make use of the AngularJS version of the "jquery-file-upload" plugin that can be found [here](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the *jQuery File Upload Plugin* for *AngularJS*?
I've used this for a few months ago, was not disappointed :)

[To the jQuery-File-Upload-Plugin-Page](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want to have a little fun doing it yourself,

I guess you could use the $http service to create a post request using the correct MIME. You would just have to create the headers.

Now if you are wondering how to select files, you would just have to use an input with type 'file' in the HTML (via a directive for instance).

If you want to play with your file before uploading them, you have the HTML5 api for HTML5 compliant browsers.

But you might also have to manage the fallback to a flash based uploading method for non html5 enabled browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this one? It's interesting.
[Angular File Upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload)